# Unable to perform JNDI lookup in WebLogic 12 server from JBoss Wildfly 8

Tags: java, jms, weblogic12c, wildfly-8

I am trying to put a message in JMS queue in WebLogic server. My application is running in Wildfly 8 AS. I have written the code for the JNDI lookup and then putting message in JMS queue. I am using the following code for initializing the InitialContext:

```
private static InitialContext getInitialContext(String url) throws NamingException {
        Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<>();
        env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_FACTORY);
        env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
        return new InitialContext(env);
    }
```

I have added the following Maven dependencies for adding the WebLogic jar

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>weblogic</groupId>
        <artifactId>webservices</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

But the maven dependencies are not getting resolved. Do I need to add any maven repository?

If anything else is required, can anyone please guide me on that?

Regards,
Anirban.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Weblogic does not provide client jar artifact in maven repository. You must get the `wlthint3client.jar` located in the `WL_HOME\server\lib` directory of your weblogic server. This jar contains all classes needed by clients calling the weblogic server.

Then you can install it manually in your maven repository and use it as a maven dependency in your `pom.xml`

Finally, you can lookup the `InitialContext` using the `weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory` factory.

Comment: Where can I get `wlthint3client.jar`? I don't setup Weblogic, I just consume message.

Comment: @KevinBui You need to set this up - you cannot get these jarfiles without setting up weblogic, and using the maven installer to install them to your maven repo. Its either that or gain access to a custom maven repository that already has these installed, and download them from there.

Answer (score 0):

The Checked answer is actually wrong, although it may have been correct at the time of writing.

You can do the same thing as including `weblogic.jar` (which is just a meta-inf with a bunch of classpath entries) in maven by including

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.weblogic</groupId>
    <artifactId>weblogic-server-pom</artifactId>
    <version>12.2.1-4-0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

in your maven POM - of course, replacing the version with the version you have in your `.m2` folder. (if you have none, nothing will work and youll have to look up in the weblogic docs how to install weblogic maven artifacts into your local maven repo for your version of weblogic)

This essentially is a dependency listing to mirror `weblogic.jar`
It doesnt work for every situation, as some instances (usually instances requiring the use of `wlManagementMBean.jar`) of use require the use of a hardcoded weblogic installation paths (for that you have to add weblogic.jar to the classpath directly)

But it should work with projects utilizing Weblogic JNDI lookups and JMS server apis, among other things

Please note: your first run with maven will take a few minutes, as maven automatically tries to check maven central for artifact updates, regardless of local installation